# How can I fix "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'predict')" for Tensorflow.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow.js

In short I've have a trained model I'd like to use for detecting different recyclable objects. I have tried different way to load the model and use the model.predict() but I keep getting the error "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'predict')"

```
const Result = {
    0: "aerosol",
    1: "battery",
    2: "cardboard",
    3: "food can",
    4: "glass bottle",
    5: "ink cartridge",
    6: "magazine",
    7: "paper bag",
    8: "plastic bag",
    9: "plastic bottle",
    10: "plastic utensils",
    11: "soda can"
  };
  
  const imageSelector = document.getElementById("image-selector");
  const selectedImage = document.getElementById("selected-image");

  const model = await tf.loadGraphModel('model/model.json').then(model => {
    console.log(model);
    });

  
  imageSelector.addEventListener("change", getUploadImage);
  function getUploadImage() {
    const file = this.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
  
    reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
      const dataURL = reader.result;
      selectedImage.setAttribute("src", dataURL);
      predictionList.innerHTML = "";
    });
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
  
  const predictButton = document.getElementById("predictBtn");
  const resultList = document.getElementById("list");
  
  predictButton.addEventListener("click", async function () {
    const image = selectedImage;
    const pre_image = tf.browser.fromPixels(image, 3)
      .resizeNearestNeighbor([256, 256])
      .expandDims()
      .toFloat()
      .reverse(-1);
    const predict_result = await model.predict(pre_image).data();
    console.log(predict_result);
    const order = Array.from(predict_result)
      .map(function (p, i) {
        return {
          probability: p,
          className: Result[i]
        };
      }).sort(function (a, b) {
        return b.probability - a.probability;
      }).slice(0, 2);
  
    resultList.innerHTML = "";
    order.forEach(function (p) {
      resultList.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<li>${p.className}: ${parseInt(Math.trunc(p.probability * 100))} %</li>`);
    });
  });
```

[Here's the error on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbuoG.png)

Edit: On that respect I noticed that the model is not properly loading.

Comment: Why the `.then(model => { console.log(model); })`? You just broke the Promise chain there.

Comment: I was just following a previous post about solving the issues. It seems be working after removing it.